# Servo or Stepper, which is best for forward and backward rotational or linear motion (Horizontal)

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor, servo

Im designing a simple system which holds a weight of around 5Kg in a platform. The platform semi rotates on a center point. 20 or 30 degrees both direction. There could be maximum kg of weight on the platform.

So its like below ddesign

[image]

There I marked the red x to say it rotates maximum up to those points.

So my query is which is best for this purpose , Servo or Stepper. Also any suggestion about motor specification for that scenario. Im using Arduino to control. and thinking about 2 motors(Is it required). Also I need to control the speed of rotation.

Comment: There is no answer to this without knowing your requirements for speed, acceleration profile, and positional accuracy. You also haven't told us about the size of the platform. 5kg at 10cm radius rotating slowly and 5kg at 1m rotating fast have very different torque and power requirements, and a stepper is only suitable for one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Stepper is much simpler to implement than servo. The stepper is open loop control, meanwhile the servo is closed loop control, so you would need an encoder feedback.

The stepper makes noise and vibrates, the servo is smooth. IMO in both cases you would need a transmission, like gearhead, belt, sprockets,..

Comment: Sorry, which is having more power and smoother motion.. like without any jerking movement?

Comment: @sforsandeep Power is related to the size of the motor, both types come in many power ratings. Smoother is servo, as said before yet.